# Opening SSH Tunnel with Subprocess.Popen is not going to the Background after using communicate()

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, subprocess, popen, tunnel

When I use Popen to establish an ssh tunnel(using these ssh flags  -f -N -L ) it hangs in the console window. I can confirm the tunnel is up but the rest of my application does not run, it freezes at this point. If I close the console window then the tunnel also shuts down. So it looks as if this process is running in the foreground which is the behaviour I don't want.

```
    launchtunnel = subprocess.Popen('ssh tunnel command', 
                                    shell=True, 
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    launchtunnel.communicate()[0]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This solved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975251/python-subprocess-popen-and-ssh-port-forwarding-in-the-background

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python subprocess.Popen and ssh port forwarding in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975251/python-subprocess-popen-and-ssh-port-forwarding-in-the-background)